# Alternative to pjax/djax and ajaxy

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I was evaluating jQuery plugins to make a Drupal 7 site using AJAX everywhere. I have been using [ajaxy](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-ajaxy). But it does not seem to be very actively maintained.

Two possible solutions I have found are [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) and [djax](https://github.com/beezee/djax). What are your experiences with those plugins?

What other plugins do you know that do similar functionality? Very important features are SEO friendliness (preferably using pushState so no hash is being used. Hashes are used as a fallback for not supported browsers.). And also has to be very flexible since it has to wirk with Drupal's HTML structure.

Comment: pjax doesn't use hash fallbacks (which is good imo), so if you need those you can rule pjax out

Comment: Why is this good? This way the same functionality could be implemented. It doesn't rule out pjax but it requires me to think about other behavior of my website for unsupported browsers. Maybe there should an option in pjax for my desired behavior?

Comment: yes there is - loading the link normally when history is not supported

Comment: What if a reload has a big impact on the behavior of the website? This should be an option...

Answer (score 1):

Drupal provides its own [AJAX framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) that [can easily be used to *ajaxify* links](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/make-link-use-ajax-drupal-7-its-easy). You don't get to write any JavaScript code as [many *AJAX commands* are already provided](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7). The solution is SEO friendly. Links are outputted with a `nojs` element in their path which is then replaced by `ajax` when used by the framework.

See the [AJAX Example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7), [AJAX Graceful Degradation](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/group/ajax_degradation_example/7) and [AJAX Commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_advanced.inc/7) example modules for API usages.

Answer (score 1):

Go with pjax, it is easy to implement and SEO Friendly.  For unsupported browsers, mainly below IE 10 it simply fallsback to the default browser behavior (without any work on your part).

I have used pjax on a handful of projects successfully and plan to use it on many more.

You can find more info on pjax [HERE](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

And since you mentioned your using Drupal, you may find [this article](https://www.drupal.org/project/pjax) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using PHP and jQuery, the best bet would be **my project**, phery http://phery-php-ajax.net, it's actively maintained, and I've been improving it for the last 2 years.

through using views, you can either segment your site in individual ajax views, or use the full blown page content through AJAX. it's SEO friendly, and since it uses event delegation, all new elements are already ajaxified. It doesn't enforce to use history API or hash events, you may decide the best funcionality for you.

a full blown AJAX loading content for your site would be (only the container, leaving out menus, footers, etc, of course)

```js
    var ever_pushed = false; // needed for chrome

    phery.view({
        '#container': {
            'exclude': ['/blog'], // exclude wordpress from it
            'beforeSend': function(){
                $('body,html').scrollTop(0); // go to the top
            },
            'render': function(html, data, passdata){
                var $this = $(this);
                nav_items.removeClass('current').filter('.' + data.controller).addClass('current'); // update the menu
                document.title = data.title; // set the document title

                /* Good browsers get history API */
                if (typeof passdata['popstate'] === 'undefined') {
                    window.history.pushState(data, data.title, data.url);
                    ever_pushed = true;
                }

                _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]); // Google analytics

                $('#content')
                .find('>div')
                .animate({'opacity':0}, 375) // fadeout
                .promise()
                .done(function(){
                    $body.removeClass().addClass(data.body_class);
                    $this.html('').html(html);
                    on_reload(); // restart events that need to be bound on new elements
                    cufonize(true); //apply cufon
                    $('#content').find('>div').animate({'opacity':1}, 375); // fadein
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
        if (!ever_pushed) {
            return;
        }
        phery.view('#container').navigate_to(document.location.toString(), null, {'popstate':true}); // back and forward history buttons
    });
```

a smaller version of the same code would be:

```js
$(function(){
    var ever_pushed = false;
    phery.view({
        '#container': {
            'afterHtml': function(html, data, passdata){
                /* Good browsers get history API */
                if (typeof passdata['popstate'] === 'undefined') {
                    window.history.pushState(data, data.title, data.url);
                    ever_pushed = true;
                }

            }
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
        if (!ever_pushed) {
            return;
        }
        phery.view('#container').navigate_to(document.location.toString(), null, {'popstate':true}); // back and forward history buttons
    });
});
```

in your PHP side, it would be:

```php
function render_view($data, $params, $phery){
   return PheryResponse::factory()->render_view(views_get_view('all_projects')->execute_display('Block', array()));
}
//...
public function render($reset = FALSE){
   Phery::instance()->views(array(
     '#container' => array($this, 'render_view')
   ))->process();
}
//...
```

Comment: You *must* disclose when linking to your own product/project.

Comment: This is a nice tool. But the Drupal AJAX framework as suggested in the other answer is extremely powerful. I think it would be harder to get your script working with Drupal than its own framework.

Comment: indeed, but it can fit any framework without much work. the javascript part can be simplified

Comment: I took a look at that AJAX framework and looks really obtrusive and convoluted... well, it's up to you ;)